# Error when trying to use code splitting with webpack/angular 2/.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack

So im trying to make a reasonably robust template webpack config file for my angular 2 apps but I'm getting an error when trying to split up my files.

So this is the error im getting:

> vendor.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined(anonymous function)
>   polyfills.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

note: with the polyfills.js webpack actually produces two of the files that are different, not sure if this is meant to happen

When trying to load the files in in a Index.cshtml file served by MVC, I have them loaded in the order: `vendor.js`, `polyfills.js`, `app.js`

Any ideas why I might be getting these errors? also if there's some optimization of this then feel free to mention it

Here is my Common webpack file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('extendify')({ isDeep: true, arrays: 'concat' });
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');
var currentEnv = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
var currentEnvConfig = require('./webpack.' + currentEnv)

 var common =  {   
        resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: currentEnv != 'dev' ?   extractCSS.extract(['css']) : 'css-loader'},
            { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'}
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        app: './app/main.ts',
        vendor: ['./app/vendor.ts'],
       pollfills: ['./app/polyfills.ts']
    },
    output: {
        path: 'wwwroot/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.js"),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"polyfills", /* filename= */"polyfills.js")
        //new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //    name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        //}),
    ]
};
 if (currentEnv != 'dev'){
     common = merge(common, currentEnvConfig)
 }
 module.exports = common;
```

and my prod one - test and dev webpack config files currently don't have anything so I didn't include

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ENV = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = 'production';

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
              'ENV': 'prod'
          }
      })
    ]
};
```

Update:
If I change the order of the files to this

```
<script src="~/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/app.js"></script>
```

Then I instead get these errors

> vendor.js:12571 Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decoratorscheckReflect
>   vendor.js:32248 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy' of undefined

but I have `reflect-metadata` in my `polyfills.ts` as below

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```